# how to make auto reload with Spring-boot on IDEA Intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I had wrote a project base on Spring-boot,tomcat,freemarker, I run it successful, but whenever I modify some templates and java class, I must restart server or use "reload changed classes" menu on Intellij to make the changes become effective. It wastes lots time!

Then I try to use springloaded  as [the official said](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-reload-java-classes-without-restarting):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

then I rerun server, but doesn't work as expected!
I still need to restart server after any change on template or class.

How could I configure the springloaded to auto reload.
Thanks a lot!

---

The version of Spring-boot is 1.3.0RC1

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RC1</version>
</parent>
```

maven version:3.2
jdk:1.8
intellij :14.1.5
os:windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: which spring-boot version are you using? If i remember correctly the reload of java classes is possible since 1.3.0 (only RC1 available right now). But I'm not sure about this. You may verify this

Comment: I use Spring-boot 1.3.0RC1

Comment: :( Sorry then i can't tell you more. Didn't try this, yet

Comment: Maybe somehow unrelated, but autoreloading works out of the box in netbeans.

Answer (score 185):

First, be sure that you added `spring-boot-devtools` as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Second, verify that the option check-box `File->Setting –> Build, Execution, Deployment –> Compiler–>`**Build project automatically** is selected.

Last, press `SHIFT+CTRL+A` for Linux/Windows users or `Command+SHIFT+A` for Mac users, then type **registry** in the opened pop-up window. Scroll down to `Registry...` using the down arrow key and hit `ENTER` on `Registry...`. In the `Registry` window verify the option **compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running** is checked.

If the static files are not reloaded, press `CTRL+F9` to force a reload.

The instructions above are taken from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/intellij-idea-spring-boot-template-reload-is-not-working/)

Comment: Thanks it works, Do you know if its possible when running it with command line ?

Comment: Its still not working. had it working for 5 other projects but you know f me right???

Comment: Do you know how to increase the speed?

Comment: Note that this has moved to the Advanced Settings: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274903/In-IntelliJ-2021.2-compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running-disappear.-Unable-to-enable-live-reload-under-Spring-boot#focus=Comments-27-5089338.0-0

Answer (score 123):

Note :: For who those not found that option in registry.The newer version of intellij idea for my case @Version:2021.2 the compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running option is moved to advanced settings:

[image]

Answer (score 26):

For macOS

1. Preference -> Compiler -> check "Build project automatically"
   [image: asds]
2. shift + command + A
   [image]

[image]

check `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`

If the static files are not reloaded, press `CTRL+F9` to force a reload.

Comment: The registry item has moved to a checkbox in Advanced Settings: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274903/In-IntelliJ-2021.2-compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running-disappear.-Unable-to-enable-live-reload-under-Spring-boot#focus=Comments-27-5089338.0-0

Answer (score 9):

`CTRL+F9` to make project with debugging.
The idea is to make the project automatically work while not running or debugging!

> Setting->Build->Compiler->check Make project automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly you could check if build is fired on any changes on **Build Tools** *settings*
[image]

Comment: in addition with the answer above :  check compiler to make auto restart automatically.

Answer (score 3):

[image: intelij reload]

setting>>Build,Execution,Deployment>>Build Tools

**any changes should be checked**

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else did. I ticked the option in Advanced Settings, and under Build => Compiler, and I had the dev tools dependency. This was the final required step for me