# How can I enable auto build and auto restart with spring boot kotlin intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, kotlin, spring-kotlin

I want to rebuild project automatically when i edit project files.

So, I tried spring-boot-devtools, and Intellij seettings.

I Checked [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349456/how-to-make-auto-reload-with-spring-boot-on-idea-intellij).

Hoever, I always have to restart project manually when I edit files in spring boot project.

What is problem ?

My build setting file is bellow.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

/* auto restart */

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.1.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.50"

}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Intellij settings [image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution